# Issue with a two-dimensional array and symmetry

Tags: java, arrays, io

I am having an issue with my current project trying to figure out how to create a matrix and see if it is symmetrical.  I am also required to show how many rows it contains and how many columns it has.

The input file has the numbers:

```
3
8 5 -6 7
-19 5 17 32
3 9 2 54
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatrixSymmetry {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File f = new File("testwork.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
        int numRows = in.nextInt();

        ArrayList<Integer> columnCheck = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int numColumns = 0;

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {  
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(in.nextLine());
            numColumns++;

            while (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
                columnCheck.add(scnr.nextInt());
            }
            scnr.close();
        }

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String matrix = in.nextLine();
            Scanner matrixScan = new Scanner(matrix);

            int[][] numArray = new int[numRows][numColumns];

            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {

                for (int j=0; j < numColumns; j++) {

                    numArray[i][j] = matrixScan.nextInt();

                    if (numArray[i][j] == numArray[j][i]) {
                        System.out.println("The Matrix is Symmetric");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("The Matrix is not Symmetric");
                    }
                }
            }
            matrixScan.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Number of rows: " + numRows + 
                        "\nNumber of columns: " + numColumns);
            in.close();
    }
}
```

The output I receive is:

```
Number of rows: 3
Number of columns: 4
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of just posting the code, can you explain what you do? Will be more easy to read then, for example by adding comments that explain the intend behind some lines.

Comment: The second while doesn't seem reachable by the look of it. Also its not readable in terms of what is tried out there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: how can a 3x4 matrix be symmetric?

Answer (score 0):

in the second `while`, your `in` has reached the end of the file and `hasNext()` will return false.